# How to test whether one git commit can reach another?

Tags: git

I have two git commit IDs. How can I tell if either is a derivative of the other (and if so, which one)?

In other words, can one git commit reach the other git commit by following parent commit pointers?

I'm hoping for a simple git command that will produce a result that I may interpret into a Boolean.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005392/how-can-i-tell-if-one-commit-is-a-descendant-of-another-commit